# failed with exit status 69

Tags: macos, python-2.7

I'm trying to install a Python package (PIP) junos-eznc on MAC OS X Yosemite V10.10.1 and I'm not sure why i'm getting the following error?

"error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 69"

**That's the output log:**

```
mac231s-MacBook-Air:~ macbookair$ pip install junos-eznc
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): junos-eznc in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking lxml>=3.2.4 (from junos-eznc)
  Downloading lxml-3.4.1.tar.gz (3.5MB): 3.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Downloading/unpacking ncclient>=0.4.1 (from junos-eznc)
  Downloading ncclient-0.4.3.tar.gz (55kB): 55kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/ncclient/setup.py) egg_info for package ncclient

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from junos-eznc)
Downloading/unpacking scp>=0.7.0 (from junos-eznc)
  Downloading scp-0.8.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/scp/setup.py) egg_info for package scp

Downloading/unpacking jinja2>=2.7.1 (from junos-eznc)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz (378kB): 378kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/jinja2/setup.py) egg_info for package jinja2

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'custom_fixers'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
Downloading/unpacking PyYAML>=3.10 (from junos-eznc)
  Downloading PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz (248kB): 248kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/PyYAML/setup.py) egg_info for package PyYAML

Downloading/unpacking netaddr (from junos-eznc)
  Downloading netaddr-0.7.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB): 1.5MB downloaded
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>0.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ncclient>=0.4.1->junos-eznc)
Downloading/unpacking markupsafe (from jinja2>=2.7.1->junos-eznc)
  Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/markupsafe/setup.py) egg_info for package markupsafe

Installing collected packages: lxml, ncclient, scp, jinja2, PyYAML, netaddr, markupsafe
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace


    Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.


    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 69
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip-r8LGdK-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Building lxml version 3.4.1.

Building without Cython.

Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/html

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml

/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace





Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.





error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 69

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip-r8LGdK-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/macbookair/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: please add the **full text** of the output of your install command to the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the output log to my question body.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to agree to the XCode license before you can use any of its tools, including `clang`. To do this, run this from the command line:

```
sudo xcrun cc
```

You will need to input your password (assuming your user account has administrator privileges), then go through the process of agreeing to the license. Once this is complete, you can run

```
pip install junos-eznc
```

again and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply now i'm getting this error:                In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:239:

/private/var/folders/g_/4gqvq3096kg5sg6thyyh3j4h0000gp/T/pip_build_macbookair/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found

#include "libxml/xmlversion.h"

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Comment: It worked fine with this command:  STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml. Many thanks for your support :)